# Как происходит преобразование числа в число в Python?

Tags: python, производительность

Имеется списковое включение, преобразующее все элементы списка (в котором есть ТОЛЬКО числа и числа в строковом типе данных) в числа. Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста, как происходит преобразование числа в число? То-есть int(1), к примеру. Не лучше ли делать проверку на тип данных, перед преобразованием, чтобы не потерять в производительности при преобразовании числа в число или производительность не теряется?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструктор `int` сам делает проверку типа аргумента, и если это `int`, возвращает его без изменений, так что быстрее будет просто использовать `int` без дополнительных проверок. По крайней мере в CPython.

```
>>> x = 123123123123
>>> int(x) is x
True
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4946

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/abstract.c#L1371

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Long

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_CheckExact

Comment: `123123123123 * 10 // 2 // 5 is 123123123123` тоже True, но это не значит, что вычисления не производились)

Comment: @vp_arth поэтому я и определил x в отдельной строке, и именно в интерактивном интерпретаторе, который обрабатывает код построчно, чтобы избежать оптимизаций. Попробуйте так же, результат не будет `True`. Ну и по ссылкам исходники интерпретатора и документация по некоторым используемым там функциям

Comment: для x <= 256(если не ошибаюсь), будет True =)

Comment: @vp_arth именно поэтому и 123123123123 :) И кстати, отсылку к SMBC оценил :)

Answer (score 5):

К коллайдеру!

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('x = 1212345678901234567890; int(x)', number=int(1e8)))
print(timeit('x = 1212345678901234567890; int(x) if type(x) is not int else x', number=int(1e8)))

"""
5.075638975016773
6.453564461087808
"""
```

Наличие условного оператора гораздо больше влияет на время исполнения, чем то, что мы хотим оптимизировать =)